# Arquillian Shrinkwrap provide custom settings.xml file

Tags: jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I have set up a arquillian project and it all works fine locally but when running the maven build on our continuous integration box it fails. I managed to get to the bottom of the problem and it is because the maven user settings.xml file on the CI box actually has some server definitions (for another project) whereas locally to my machine it is the default file (with no servers defined). The tests throw a RuntimeException because the MavenResolver goes looking for settings-security.xml file which doesn't exist on the CI box.

I would prefer not to go adding the settings-security.xml and instead would like to provide the resolver with a 'empty' settings.xml file, or even better, tell it not to use one. Is this possible?

I tried the answer from this thread https://developer.jboss.org/thread/174873 which pretty much says to add the following option to the failsafe plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.9</version><!-- or upper -->
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                   <org.apache.maven.user-settings>nonExistentSetting.xml</org.apache.maven.user-settings>
                             </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If i do this and provide an xml file that doesnt exist all work fine from the command line running 'mvn clean install' but when i debug within my IDE it still fails.

Is there a way i can either:
Tell the maven resolver not to use a settings.xml / use a 'default' file
Create an empty settings.xml in my project and tell the maven resolver to use that

I did try the following line in my code to build my archive but it didnt seem to have an effect:

```
.addAsLibraries(Maven.configureResolver().fromFile("test-settings.xml").loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile())
```

Thanks for any help,
Craig

Answer (score 0):

ShrinkWrap resolver by default loads settings-security.xml from

```
DEFAULT_SETTINGS_SECURITY_PATH = userHome == null ? ".settings-security.xml" : userHome.concat("/.m2/settings-security.xml").replace('/', File.separatorChar);
```

but you can override this location by setting

```
System.setProperty(MavenSettingsBuilder.ALT_SECURITY_SETTINGS_XML_LOCATION,
            "someDir/empty-settings-security.xml");
```

When alternative location (non-empty string) is provided theoretically it should skip the default location. However I am not 100% sure this method will work.